# Dispatch action periodically in NGRX 8 and Angular

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I can't find similar functionality in NGRX documentation. But also I have no big experience in that library.

But - there is a possibility to dispatch action (and effect to send GET request to backend) periodically?

For example, if first dispatch action got empty response - re-dispatch action after 5 minutes.

Comment: You can set up your effect to call API again and again. i.e. you can use RXJS `interval` to call API as per the specified duration. Having effect setup to call periodically, you need not to dispatch action again and again. Dispatch only once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NgRx Effects is the right place to do this:

```
@Effect()
ping = interval(1000).pipe(mapTo(new Ping()));
```

For more info see: https://timdeschryver.dev/posts/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this

Answer (score 3):

When it is needed to have the interval argument in store, you can use:

```
    ping$ = createEffect(
        () =>
            this.actions$.pipe(ofType(startPinging)).pipe(
                withLatestFrom(this.store.select(pingPeriodAsMs)),
                exhaustMap(([_, pingPeriodAsMs]) => timer(pingPeriodAsMs, pingPeriodAsMs)),
                mapTo(ping())
            ),
        { dispatch: true }
    );
```

#### Actions

- `startPinging`: the start of the loop is requested
- `ping`: an iteration of the loop occured, ping!

#### Reducers

- `pingPeriodAsMs`: number, amount of time between two pings (in the example of code given, this value is also used for the delay of the first ping).

#### RxJS

##### Functions

- [`timer`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/timer)

##### Operators

- [`withLatestFrom`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/withLatestFrom)
- [`exhaustMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/exhaustMap)
- [`mapTo`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mapTo)

#### EDITS

Supposing that at some point we need to stop interval (thanks @AhammadaliPK for the question), the following code should do the trick:

```
  private stopPinging$ = new Subject<void>();

  ping$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(ofType(startPinging)).pipe(
        withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(pingPeriodAsMs))),
        exhaustMap(([_, pingPeriodAsMs]) =>
          timer(pingPeriodAsMs).pipe(
            takeUntil(this.stopPinging$)
          )
        ),
        mapTo(ping())
      ),
    { dispatch: true }
  );

  stopPinging() {
    this.stopPinging$.next();
  }
```

Comment: then at some point we need to stop interval, how we can achieve with same effects ?

Comment: @AhammadaliPK I edited my answer to take in account the stop of the pinging, sorry for the delay...